group by and group by and then count the groups when in another column a specific value is within the group
im absolute new to oracle sql and not able to solve following task,
Im even not sure if group by is the way to go.
I have a Table like this

As u can see it is first grouped by the session and in the second step its is then grouped by "hash".
If there is one success = true within in the sub group the entire group will count as success in the oder case it is count as unsuccess.
Im even not able to groub by group by not to mention the count of the groups.
I would need an approach on how to solve this.
Thank you in advance.
Best regards

You can GROUP BY hash and then find the MAXimum success value in the group and then use conditional aggregation over the entire result set to count the groups with each success-type:
SELECT COUNT(CASE MAX(success) WHEN 'true'  THEN 1 END) AS count_true,
       COUNT(CASE MAX(success) WHEN 'false' THEN 1 END) AS count_false
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY sessn, hash

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (success, sessn, hash) AS
  SELECT 'true',  'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'true',  'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'a', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'a', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'a', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'true',  'b', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'b', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'true',  'c', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'd', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'd', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'true',  'e', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'e', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'false', 'e', 6 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



COUNT_TRUE
COUNT_FALSE




4
2



fiddle

Hi MT0, thank you for your fast response. Your solution does not 100% match to what i'm searching for but shows me a direction i can go. Your solution ignores the session column. You can see it in this example. Due to data there must be seven counts but your statements count still 6 in total:
fiddle

@Denyo Then GROUP BY sessn, hash. Updated.

Thanks MT0, i'm already modifiying your solution to meet my requirements. I'm testing it and if everything fits, i'll mark your answer.
